# Running a sql select command with a vba string variable that contains an apostrophe

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, vba

Using VBA, I'm trying to select data from a SQL table, but am running into an issue because the Customer name I'm looking up contains an apostrophe (McDonald's). Instead of using a replace function, I'm trying to setup customerName as a parameter to avoid this issue.

```
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
        customerName = .Range("customerName")

        queryCustomers = "select * from Customers where CustomerName = '" & customerName & "'"

        'Open a connection to SQL Server
        conn.Open cnstring

        With cmd
         .CommandText = queryCustomers
         .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@param1", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, customerName)
         .ActiveConnection = conn
         .CommandType = adCmdText
        End With

        Set rs = cmd.Execute
```

I'm getting the same error because of the apostrophe which means the parameter setup I'm using is incorrect. In summary, I need help to make my queryCustomers string pass customerName as a parameter so the apostrophe in customerName does not affect the SQL command.

Comment: You need to pass these values as parameters, not because it causes you problems, but because of the problems it will avoid. Your code is wide open to sql injection. You can read more about how bad this anti-pattern is [here](https://bobby-tables.com/). That site also has examples of how to properly parameterize values.

Comment: Check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) - absolute classic!! And then **learn** from it and ***NEVER EVER*** do that again!

Comment: When you use a parameter the code will automatically escape any characters, if it needs to. The problem is because you aren't using parameters.

Comment: try this https://evona.nl/simple-parameterized-queries-using-ado-in-vba/

Comment: @Larnu so do you know how to fix that? I'm not familiar with using parameters here. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your

```
queryCustomers = "select * from Customers where CustomerName = '" & customerName & "'"
```

gets evaluated to

```
"select * from Customers where CustomerName = 'McDonald's'"
```

There is no variable where the value can be placed. This is what is executed

Try something like this

```
cmd.CommandText = "select * from Customers where CustomerName = @Value1"
Dim param1 As ADODB.Parameter
Set param1 = cmd.CreateParameter("@Value1", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 8, "McDonald's")
cmd.Parameters.Append param1
```

This approach should escape your McDonald's -> McDonald''s automatically.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 
`cmd.CommandText = "select * from Customers where CustomerName = @Value1"`
        `Dim param1 As ADODB.Parameter`
        `Set param1 = cmd.CreateParameter("@Value1", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 50, customerName)`
        `cmd.Parameters.Append param1`


        `Set rs = cmd.Execute`
returns an error on the execute line: "the connection cannot be used to perform this operation. it is either closed or invalid in this context."

Comment: Ah I had to set cmd activeconnection to fix that. But I still get an error: "Must declare the scalar variable "@Value1"

Comment: @Codelinsky use ordinal parameters instead of named ones. `cmd.CommandText = "select * from Customers where CustomerName = ?"`

Comment: Worked. Thank you :)